# Do <style> tags work in Markdown?

Tags: html, css, github, markdown

I'm writing a Github README.md file, and i have diferent tables. The contents are different, so table width is different too.

I want, at least the first column to be of fixed width, so i tried adding this before all the tables in the Markdown file:

```
<style>td:nth-child(odd){width:200px}</style>
```

Surprisingly that is working in my editor preview, but when committed to github, the text appears with the style tags stripped, and no style is applied.

My questions is if it's possible on github, and id it is, how do i do it.

Comment: I don't believe so - but you could always check the source code: https://github.com/github/markup

Comment: Is the style tag still there in the rendered page? View the source. If it isn't, then GitHub's stripping it out intentionally. If it is there, then your CSS rule isn't of higher priority than GitHub's.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Just tested it myself.

```
<style>
#foo {color: red}
</style>

<p id="foo">foo</p>

<p style="color: blue">bar</p>
```

The above rendered to:

```
#foo {color: red}
<p>foo</p>

<p>bar</p>
```

GitHub strips style tags and attributes preventing you from changing the style on their pages. This is probably for security reasons. If you could inject css into GitHub pages, you could easily launch a phishing attack.

Comment: Thanks! That sucks in a lot of ways ;) but its probably, as you said, for safety reasons.

Comment: shall we include style file externally with markdown

Comment: Github does not strip style tags: https://github.github.com/gfm/

Comment: Except it does escape it: https://github.github.com/gfm/#:~:text=quot%3B%26gt%3B%3C/p%3E-,6.11Disallowed,-Raw%20HTML%20(extension

Comment: @Johann GitHub **does** strip `<style>` tags: https://github.github.com/gfm/#disallowed-raw-html-extension-

Comment: This behavior does not reproduce today. Probably it's changed in the years since 2013. Trying the same input today, the literal `<style>` and `</style>` appear as text in the output, in addition to the content between them. (That's the same behavior documented at the link https://github.github.com/gfm/#disallowed-raw-html-extension- from the previous comment.)

Answer (score 0):

It's working only with height and width so far.

```
  <img style="width:500px" src="xyz.png"/>
```