# Markdown no break (nobr)?

Tags: html, markdown, line-breaks

I've got a phone number in my markdown that tends to break over the end of the line. In HTML I could wrap it in a `<nobr>` tag to have it keep together properly. What is the correct way to do this in markdown? [image: screenshot of my problem]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use [non-break hyphen character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2011/index.htm) ( `&#x2011;` )

```
1&#x2011;111&#x2011;111&#x2011;1111
```

for

```
1-111-111-1111
```

Or you could need the phone number format with spaces in between, then use [no-break space character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) ( `&#160;` )

```
1&#160;111&#160;111&#160;1111
```

for

```
1 111 111 1111
```

Comment: The memorable and widespread HTML code of [Non-breaking Space](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/n/nbsp.htm) `&#160;` is `&nbsp;`.

Comment: I know this is a very old post, but I'm trying to use the non-breaking hyphen character, and while it does indeed prevent line breaks, it's being rendered as more narrow than a regular dash (-) character, almost to the point of looking like a dot instead of a dash. Even in a monospaced font I'm seeing it rendered in an oddly narrow looking form, which could be confusing. (As per the Markdown preview in IntelliJ idea, I'm hoping it won't end up looking so bad on Github.) This is documentation for command line options, like `--foo`, where you definitely don't want line breaks.

Comment: @kshetline I would suggest to use solution from other answer for you case. That is to use CSS. I imagine the `--foo` is within `<code>` block as rendered in HTML. So you might create CSS rule `code { white-space:nowrap; }` or try `hyphens: none`…

Comment: @mahish, I'd love to use CSS, but unfortunately since this is markdown for a README file, I've got no control over the Markdown viewer that might be used. On the plus side, it turns out this looks fine on Github, where I most care about the appearance.

Answer (score 32):

Apparently I didn't realize you could just embed html in markdown.

```
<nobr>[1-111-111-1111](tel:11111111)</nobr>
```

works fine

Comment: See [Raw HTML](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.19/#raw-html) in the CommonMark Spec.

Comment: The `<nobr>` tag is not standard html and shouldn't be used https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nobr

Comment: @Jeff Walker Code Ranger so what is the alternative ?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a span with inline styles in your markdown

```html
<span style="white-space:nowrap;">[1-111-111-1111](tel:11111111)</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

The 'nobr' tag is non-standard HTML, and while it is supported by browsers for legacy purposes, the correct way is to handle it via CSS.

CSS equivalent:

```
.nobr   { white-space:nowrap; }
```

Comment: > _"the correct way is to handle it"_

Which unfortunately does not work if you are typing content where you have no control over CSS, such as in a GitHub Markdown file. You can add HTML but not CSS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20599838/102699  #fwiw

Comment: if you can add html you can add inline styling.