# How to set minimum width for Markdown table column?

Tags: gitlab, markdown

For some reason, the `Date` column involves unexpected line breaks as below:

[image]

Don't know the reason. Is there any way to fix the width so that all the dates are displayed in one line? Thanks!

BTW, the markdown is on GitLab.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Markdown no break (nobr)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30308032/markdown-no-break-nobr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can embed HTML in your markdown file. So, you can wrap your dates in `<nobr> ... </nobr>` tags.

Comment: <nobr> does not work in GitLab markdown. However, the link you sent solved the problem. I just need to replace '-' with &#x2011; to prevent line break

Comment: Glad to hear it. The thing with wrapping MD in HTML tags is that you have to put at least one empty line around the tags. Best of luck!

Comment: Nice trick but it will not help if the cell content is not text (like an image for instance)