# Span element in Markdown

Tags: html, css, markdown

I wrote a markdown.md with the following lines of code.

```html
<span style="font-family: Open Sans; font-weight: 300; font-size: 16px; font-style: normal">300 Light normal hamburgefonstiv</span>
<br /> <span style="font-family: Open Sans; font-weight: 300; font-size: 16px;font-style: italic">300 Light italic hamburgefonstiv</span>
<br /> <span style="font-family: Open Sans; font-weight: 400; font-size: 16px; font-style: normal">400 Regular normal hamburgefonstiv</span>
<br /> <span style="font-family: Open Sans; font-weight: 400; font-size: 16px;font-style: italic">400 Regular italic hamburgefonstiv</span>
<br /> <span style="font-family: Open Sans; font-weight: 600; font-size: 16px; font-style: normal">600 Semibold normal hamburgefonstiv</span>
<br /> <span style="font-family: Open Sans; font-weight: 600; font-size: 16px;font-style: italic">600 Semibold italic hamburgefonstiv</span>
<br /> <span style="font-family: Open Sans; font-weight: 700; font-size: 16px; font-style: normal">700 Bold normal hamburgefonstiv</span>
<br /> <span style="font-family: Open Sans; font-weight: 700; font-size: 16px;font-style: italic">700 Bold italic hamburgefonstiv</span>
<br /> <span style="font-family: Open Sans; font-weight: 800; font-size: 16px; font-style: normal">800 ExtraBold normal hamburgefonstiv</span>
<br /> <span style="font-family: Open Sans; font-weight: 800; font-size: 16px;font-style: italic">800 ExtraBold italic hamburgefonstiv</span>
```

When I open the browser I see this. It works fine. When I open the the markdown.md on Github I see only the textlines as normal text. What is wrong? Is the idea with a span element the right one?

[image]

Comment: https://github.github.com/gfm/ might help you.

Answer (score 4):

Although GitHub's markdown spec supports [some HTML](https://github.github.com/gfm/#raw-html), CSS is not supported at all at this time. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598628/do-style-tags-work-in-markdown):

> GitHub strips style tags and attributes preventing you from changing
>   the style on their pages. This is probably for security reasons. If
>   you could inject css into GitHub pages, you could easily launch a
>   phishing attack.