# Why is there no vertical scroll bar on my markdown file?

Tags: scroll, markdown

Here is my entire .md file. Not only do I not have a scroll bar, but anything within the "pre" tags completely changes the font of the text within it. And also the code is viisble in the output. For example, "pre { white-space: ..." is visible in the output.

```css
pre {
  white-space: pre !important;
  overflow-y: scroll !important;
  max-height: 100px !important;
}
```

```html
<pre class="table" style="max-height: 100px;">

  ### Header

  <div align="center">...body...text...</div>

  <div align="center">...body...text...</div>

  <div align="center">...body...text...</div>

  <div align="center">...body...text...</div>

  <div align="center">...body...text...</div>

  <div align="center">...body...text...</div>

  <div align="center">...body...text...</div>

</pre>
```

Comment: Which Markdown processor are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Check the **max-height** within the style tags, you forget the colon ":" at the end.

---

The issue is that you can't use style tags (I think you're using .md for a Github project or related with that), check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598628/do-style-tags-work-in-markdown) here in SO.

Comment: Just made that edit to the question. Must have deleted it when I first posted. Still no fix

Comment: Check the question linked, did that solve your issue?